# PermissionUtils cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm working on an app that will allow users to report potholes and other roadside issues easily. My specific issue is in the map I included; in the report activity that will allow users to pinpoint where the problem is by using google maps and some markers. To do this I'm basically copying code word for word from the google maps api and my problem is that the permission utils object isn't being inherited from google play services. I had put this code down for a while (out of frustration) so i dont exactly remember what the other issues were but i remember getting the code around permission utils to not give me an error was kind of a bitch. Anyway so please help ;_;. I apologize for how i space my code, it is just visually easier for me, the first block is the message activity, the second is my manifest. please let me know if I should post anything else.

```
package com.example.fixmytown;


    import java.util.List;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

    public class Message extends FragmentActivity implements OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

        private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
        private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

        private GoogleMap mMap;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.maps_frag);
            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    //----------------------------[Don't Mess with the above]------------------------------------------------------------
            android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();






    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
            //you were trying to figure out why the action bar isnt changing title. beinga bitch
            String subject = " ";

            if (Black.activityType == 1){
                subject = "Pothole";
            }
            else if (Black.activityType == 2){
                subject = "Roadkill";
            }
            else if (Black.activityType == 3){
                subject = "Pollution";
            }
            else if(Black.activityType == 4){
            //  getActionBar().setTitle("Email Public Servant ");
            }

        }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

          @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                mMap = map;

                mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
                enableMyLocation();
            }
            private void enableMyLocation() {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission to access the location is missing.
                    PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
                } else if (mMap != null) {
                    // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            }



    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

        public void sendMessage(View view) {
            EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MessageText);
            String Description = text.getText().toString();

        String subject = "";

                if (Black.activityType == 1){
                    subject = "Pothole";
                }
                else if (Black.activityType == 2){
                    subject = "Roadkill";
                }
                else if (Black.activityType == 3){
                    subject = "Pollution";
                }
                else if(Black.activityType == 4){
                //  getActionBar().setTitle("Email Public Servant ");
                }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

        //email ability 
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"mckippy@gmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , Description);
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(Message.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.message, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }


    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fixmytown"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES"/>


      <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
      <uses-permission 
            android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".Black"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_black" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".Green"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_green"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".Message"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_message" >
        </activity>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA0e26vc4-YGqmvOQSA6lQfnZyt3dmmbek"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check out this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521756/error-package-permissionutils-does-not-exist

Comment: okay so what do i do about it, create a class for permission utils? isnt that the purpose of google play services?

Comment: Did you see the answer given on that post? It provides the full class.

Comment: yeah i read the answer, im a noob to programming so i dont really understand what im supposed to do with that. isnt the purpose of google play services so that i can inheret these objects? do i create another class and slap that code in there?

Comment: Im a noob too... yeah i think you just copy/paste the missing class that you need into your project alongside the classes that you already have... just make sure to change the project line at the top to match your project (same as your other classes).. and make sure the class name exactly matches your existing references to it.

Comment: You may run into other problems such as yet another non existent reference inside this new class, but hopefully not.

Comment: Sorry if I'm waking up an old chat strain, but did you guys get it to work in the end? I keep running into problems even after copying that class in there. If you guys have completed it, I would greatly appreciate if you put the full code in answer to this question. Thanks :)